# Plotting six chosen rows of a matrix

Tags: matrix, plotting

I have a matrix,`W`, whose dimension is `n x n`, each entry is a number. I need to plot only the values of six rows, namely those labelled by the row index `i` equal to:

```
n/32, 3*n/64, n/16, 3*n/32, n/8, 3*n/16, n/4, 3*n/8
```

For every row I need to plot all of the `n` values that are in the row. 
I should end up with six plots, hopefully all in the same page.
I guess I should use ListLinePlot, but how exactly can I do that?

EDIT: instead of using the value of `i` mentioned before, I am now using `i`= 1,2,3,4, just to practise. I am following @belisarius advice, using:

```
l = {1, 2, 3, 4};
ListLinePlot[W[[l]], PlotLegends -> l]
```

to plot the 4 graphs. But I keep having the following error:

```
 Part {1,2,3,4} of (<<1>>) does not exist.
```

Why does this happen and how can I fix it?

EDIT: Here is my whole code. The problem is in the `Wab` matrix, which seems not to make sense, as I cannot plot the desired values mentioned above.

```
getA[kappa_] := 
  Table[2*Cos[(2*Pi/n)*(Abs[j - i])*kappa], {i, n}, {j, n}];
getF[csi_, a_, b_] := 
  Module[{csiInv = Inverse[csi]}, .5 Tr[csiInv.a.csiInv.b]];
getG[csi_, f_, a_] := Module[{csiInv = Inverse[csi]}, 
   csiInv.a.csiInv/2];
getE[g_, k_] := Module[{kinv = Inverse[k]},
   Transpose[kinv].g.kinv];
getW[k_, a_, e_] := Module[{ktrans = Transpose[k]},
   Tr[k.a.ktrans.e]];
getV[csi_, e_, e2_, k_] := 
  Module[{ktrans = Transpose[k], e2trans = Transpose[e2]},
   2*Tr[csi.ktrans.e.k.csi.ktrans.e2trans.k]];
getP[g_, delta_] := Module[{deltatranspose = Transpose[delta, {1}]},
   deltatranspose.g.delta];

n = L = 16;
sigma = 3;
nyquist = n/2 + 1;
sampling = 8;
mu = 0.0;

powerspectrum[i_] := 
  Piecewise[{{0, i == 0}, {Exp[-(2*Pi*i*sigma/L)^2], 
     0 < i <= n/2}, {Exp[-(2*Pi*(n - i)*sigma/L)^2], n/2 < i <= n}}];
pts = Table[powerspectrum[i], {i, 0, n - 1}] ;

inverse = InverseFourier[pts];
func[inverse_] := 
  Module[{n = Length[inverse], tup}, 
   tup = Cases[
     Tuples[Range[n], 2], {i_, j_} /; Abs[i - j] < (n - 1)/2];
   SparseArray[
    Thread[tup -> (inverse[[Abs[#1 - #2] + 1]] & @@@ tup)], {n, n}]];
CSI = func[inverse];

Kmatrix = 
  Table[((3.0*70.0*70.0*0.3)/(2.0*300000.0*300000.0))*((j + 1)*(i + 
        2 - (j + 1)))*(1.0 + (70.0/300000.0)*(j + 1)), {i, 0, 
    n - 1}, {j, 0, n - 1}];

leftREAL = 
  Table[RandomVariate[
    NormalDistribution[mu, Exp[-(2*Pi*k*sigma/L)^2]]], {k, n/2}];
rightREAL = Reverse[leftREAL] /. {x_, y_} -> {n - x, y};
fullREAL = Join[{0.0}, Most[leftREAL], rightREAL];

leftIMAGINARY = 
  Table[RandomVariate[
    NormalDistribution[mu, Exp[-(2*Pi*k*sigma/L)^2]]], {k, n/2 - 1}];
rightIMAGINARY = -Reverse[leftIMAGINARY] /. {x_, y_} -> {n - x, y};
fullIMAGINARY = Join[{0.0}, leftIMAGINARY, {0.0}, rightIMAGINARY];

fullfield = fullREAL + I*fullIMAGINARY;

fieldconfiguration = InverseFourier[fullfield];

Wab = Table[
   getW[Kmatrix, getA[beta], 
    getE[getG[CSI, getF[CSI, getA[alpha], getA[alpha]], getA[alpha], 
      Kmatrix]]], {alpha, n}, {beta, n}];
```

Answer (score 2):

```
n = 64;
l = {n/32, 3*n/64, n/16, 3*n/32, n/8, 3*n/16, n/4, 3*n/8};
m = RandomReal[{0, 1}, {n, n}];
ListLinePlot[m[[l]], PlotLegends -> l]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: thanks @belisarius I have tried to follow your advice but I get the error that you can see in the edited question

Comment: @johnhenry Then your `W` isn't a 4x4 (or larger)  matrix ...

Comment: Here is how I build the W matrix in my code:

Comment: Wab = Table[
   getW[Kmatrix, getA[beta], 
    getE[getG[CSI, getF[CSI, getA[alpha], getA[alpha]], getA[alpha], 
      Kmatrix]]], {alpha, n}, {beta, n}];

Comment: Shouldn't it be nxn?

Comment: @johnhenry Please try the code with `Wab = RandomReal[{0, 1}, {n, n}];` . If it works .... it's your matrix :)

Comment: With RandomReal it works. Then it's ultimately the Wab matrix. I cannot even post the output of the Wab matrix because it's huge and it seems as though Mathematica doesn't perform certain calculations that I want it to perform. I will add the whole code to the main question.